# addSubview beneath another UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, addsubview

I would like to be able to addSubview beneath another already existing UIView, how can I do that? I haven't been able to find anything on this.

Comment: beneath, as in under (y-axis) or behind (z-axis)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about the UIView method: `insertSubview:belowSubview:`.
It's right there in the ["Managing the View Hierarchy"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#jumpTo_93) section of the UIView docs.

Answer (score 8):

you can use :

```
[self.view insertSubview:topview belowSubview:buttomView];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift:

```
self.view.insertSubview(newView, belowSubview: yourLabel)
```